# Android OpenCV - Getting distance between two indistinct lines

Tags: java, android, opencv, edge-detection

As mentioned, I'm trying to get the distance between two indistinct lines from an image with applied edge detection. As an example please look at the below image for clarification.

[image]

As you can see, the lines are misshaped. Ideally what I would like is to get the furthest points from each line as displayed above, and calculate their distance from that. Is this possible with OpenCV? I know I can use the magnitude function to calculate the distance appropriately, but the issue comes with actually trying to find the furthest points in the first place.

Would anyone have an idea as to how I might go about this?

Comment: If you can remove one of the lines from the image, you can use [distanceTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#distancetransform) to calculate the distance from all pixels in the other line; then you got through all of the pixels in the other line, and find the one which has the largest value of the distance transform to the other line.

Comment: Hmm, you've given me an idea. I could do this for each line individually, then take the mean max distance from each other. Do you understand what I mean? I'm terrible at explaining streams of ideas that come to mind..

Comment: You don't need to do it for each line individually: you only need to do it for one line or the other. The result ought to be symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

If you know two points on those lines then you can calculate the distance using below code in OpenCV.

```
public double euclideanDistance(Point a, Point b){
    double distance = 0.0;
    try{
        if(a != null && b != null){
            double xDiff = a.x - b.x;
            double yDiff = a.y - b.y;
            distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDiff,2) + Math.pow(yDiff, 2));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Something went wrong in euclideanDistance function in "+Utility.class+" "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return distance;
}
```

I hope this helps.